# v-currency how to remove symbol from model value?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using v-currency for vuetify

```
              <v-text-field
                v-model.trim="$v.service.manual_cost_per_slot.$model"
                v-currency="{
                  currency: service.currency,
                  locale: locale,
                  allowNegative: false,
                  masked: false
                }"
                :label="$t('service.manual_cost_per_slot')"
                class="purple-input"
              />
```

The value is saved into the model along with the currency symbol and thousands separator.
How can I prevent from this? what I want to achieve is to still see the symbol and separator on the form but the value in model should be a number with no symbol or separator. I am sure I am missing something obvious here...

Comment: What is v-currency? Vuetify doesn't have this directive. Give us the link to the module.

Comment: https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/api/#parsecurrency This should help

Comment: @AneesHameed Thank you very much, indeed it was it. Sorry for asking this silly question, not sure how I missed it... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Well, as the [documentation](https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/guide/#directive) of the module says:

> ... the v-currency
>   directive always emits the formatted string instead of the number
>   value when used with v-model. To get the number value you can use the
>   [parseCurrency method](https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/api/#parsecurrency).

There's an [example](https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/api/#example) there on the page. If you want the parsed value without symbols, use that `numberValue` computed property:

```js
import { CurrencyDirective, parseCurrency } from 'vue-currency-input'

export default {
  directives: {
    currency: CurrencyDirective
  },
  data: () => ({
    value: '$1,234.50',
    locale: 'en',
    currency: 'USD'
  }),
  computed: {
    options () {
      return {
        locale: this.locale,
        currency: this.currency
      }
    },
    numberValue () {
      return parseCurrency(this.value, this.options)
      // OR using the instance method:
      // return this.$parseCurrency(this.value, this.options)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed it was it. Sorry for asking this silly question, not sure how I missed it... Thanks a lot

Comment: None of those links work anymore, and sadly there appears to be a lot of noise around v-currency-field & vue-currency-input.